# Angular library link to angular project but face Unexpected value errorr

Tags: angular

I build one angular library, and use command `ng build libraryA --watch` for my library.
Then go to `dist/libraryA` and run `npm link`

After success, then i go to my angular main project.
Add paths in `tsconfig.json` with this.

```
  "paths": {
      "libraryA": ["../my-workspace/dist/libraryA"],
    }
```

Then go to app.module.ts

Put the libraryAModule in the imports

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { libraryAModule } from 'libraryA';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    libraryAModule 
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I run `ng serve` or ng serve --aot`. Both got me this error`ERROR in Unexpected value 'libraryAModule ... `in`

Library build successed.
Angular main project also worrking fine (if without the libraryAModule)

Anyway i can run it success for my custom build library? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to install with this way without adding in paths :

```
npm install ../my-workspace/dist/libraryA
```

Comment: I tried for this solution, this is working. Thanks. But why this one is working, and if using this method, mean i cannot `npm link` also. I have to build and install again right?

Comment: @Ben no you don't have to install it each time you build the library ^^

Comment: If using this way to install it, i am using `npm build --watch  libraryA` then it will not effect the updated in my main  project.

Comment: it gonna affect your main project, I mean your main project will take  the changes into consideration

Comment: meaning? Not rreally sure what do you mean? Can you elaborate more?

Comment: I found the solution by adding the `@angular` in the paths inside `tsconfig.json` then will solve the problem. Here are answer that i found. You guys can have a look. 
 https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/35586#issuecomment-630774572